# Libraries for languages and their translation?

Tags: translation, multilingual

we are translating our website into several languages. 
Since users can add the languages they speak (and other stuff) to their profile, we need a list of all languages (and the other stuff) in different languages.

Do you know if there are libraries that provide languages, countries, ... translated into different languages?

Thanks

Comment: Questions for off-site resources are explicitly off-topic.

Comment: What framework / CMS are you using?